# Swift - Position of cell.textLabel?.text is not starting from beginning of Cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

Inside UITableView, while testing the application on iPhone 8 (simulator), the position of cell.textLabel?.text is starting as expected from begining of the cell.

But, while testing the application on iPad pro (12.9), the text is starting not as expected as you can see on below screenshot.

[image]

Any advise why like that and what is the reason?

Comment: What constraints have you applied on the `UITableView`? or you are using `UITableViewController`?

Comment: I am not using any constraints, just inside CellForRowatIndexPath, I am using cell.textlabel.text

Comment: please post code

Comment: Looking at the separator line, it seems like your table view is not fully covering the view. Check by giving background color to table-view if it is covering full view or not.

Comment: the color is covering fully the cells of tableview

Answer (score 0):

Set this

```
tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
```

From [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614849-celllayoutmarginsfollowreadablew)

> A Boolean value that indicates whether the cell margins are derived from the width of the readable content guide.

Comment: text still in the same place (Not at the beginning of the cell), but I notice that the separator lines between cells changed location form center of cell to the end of the cell. I believe if I can change the position of the separator line to the beginning, the problem will be solved.

Comment: If this is a simulator try in a device

Comment: I am not able to try it on my iPad

Comment: sign the app then  trust developer from settings